# cf9 query grid values SQL

Tags: ajax, extjs, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a grid bound to a cfc, populating an id column and a checkbox (boolean) column. onLoad, i want to get a list of ID values, but only those having checkbox = 1 
Here is the working code, with great help from Jan S

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function init(){
  var grid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('testgrid'); 
  var gs = grid.getStore();
  var records = gs.getRange();
  var filteredRecords = [];

  for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  // note: for CF, you MUST capitalize grid header names
  if (records[i].get('SELECT') === 1) {
    var thisID = records[i].get('ID');
    filteredRecords.push(thisID);
      }
    }
  document.getElementById('idList').value=filteredRecords;  
}

ColdFusion.Event.registerOnLoad(init,null,false,true);

</script>

<cfset items=QueryNew("id,Description,Select")> 
<cfset Temp=QueryAddRow(items,1)>
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"id","11")>  
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"Description","Some item")>  
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"Select",1)>  
<cfset Temp=QueryAddRow(items)>
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"id","22")>  
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"Description","Some other item")>  
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"Select",1)>  
<cfset Temp=QueryAddRow(items)>
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"id","33")>  
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"Description","A third item")>  
<cfset Temp=QuerySetCell(items,"Select",0)> 

<cfform>
<cfgrid name="testgrid" format="html" query="items">
<cfgridcolumn name="id" header="ID" select="no">
<cfgridcolumn name="Description" header="Description" select="no">
<cfgridcolumn name = "Select" header="Select" select="yes" type="boolean">
</cfgrid>
<br>
 <!--- populate this with list of ID's having the checkbox checked, here: 11,22 --->
<input type="text" name="idList" id="idList"> <input type="button" name="getList" value="Get List" onClick="init()">
</cfform>
```

Basically I need to translate into AJAX this SQL statement:

```
select stringColumn where booleanColumn = 1 from myGrid
```

I'm using Cold Fusion 9 which is based on js ext 3.1 i believe

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear in what you are looking for and include what you have tried?

Comment: a store has no render event, either store -> load or grid -> render

Comment: please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it was helpful (the hook under the down-vote arrow)

Comment: After grid refreshes, i want to select into a list values from first column but only where second column = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get an array with all a field from all records where another field is 1:

```
isData.on('load', function(store, records){
    // create a new array with all records where the 'booleanColumn' is = 1
    var filteredRecords = [];
    for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        if (records[i].get('booleanColumn') === 1) {
            filteredRecords.push(records[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(filteredRecords);

    // create a new array of 'stringColumn' values
    var filteredValues = [];
    for (i = 0; i < filteredRecords.length; i++) {
        filteredValues[i] = filteredRecords[i].get('stringColumn');
    }
    console.log(filteredValues);

   // proceed with filtered values...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jandalf, CF9 is using extjs 3.1 i believe, i get: TypeError: Ext.Array is undefined;  
 

var filteredRecords = Ext.Array.filter(records, function(record){

Comment: Do you need to support IE < 9 ? then you can use the `array.map` and `array.filter` function from the browser, I adjust my answer with it.

Comment: yes, i need to support ie8, however, firefox 28 throws the same error. thanks again

Comment: IE8 still throws "Object doesn't support this property or method" on var filteredRecords = ...  and then an "undefined is null or not an object" on var filteredValues = ...   firefox doesn't throw an error, but when i do     var filteredValues = filteredRecords.map(function(record){
        var thisList = record.get('app_id');
  alert(thisList);
  
    });   it pops up a blank (although 2 of my booleans = 1)

Comment: so now I use a `for` loop for the map and filter function, if this won't work please post what console.log prints.

Comment: it posts empty array elements, one for each record with value 1:   
[]
[]

Comment: so you get no errors? then look if you have a spelling mistake in `get('stringColumn')` then we need to look why we get an array of arrays..

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice you called the console twice, it just outputs an empty one for each call, console.log(filteredRecords) and console.log(filteredValues) I've checked spelling, capitalized column names to match ajax return. This is the actual code: if (records[i].get('BOXARRAY') === 1)... filteredValues[i] = filteredRecords[i].get('APP_ID')  And this is the Ajax return: {"QUERY":{"COLUMNS":["APP_ID","BOXARRAY"],"DATA":[["12","1"],["20","1"],["23","0"],["24","0"],["27","0"],["28","0"],["38","0"],["39","0"],["40","0"],["45","0"]]},"TOTALROWCOUNT":"40"}   Thanks again for your help!

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I've never created a fiddle and jsfiddle.net doesn't seem to support CF. I've added code to create the grid and the function you provided, right now nothing gets logged to the console. I would really appreciate if you can take another look. Thanks again and regards

Comment: maybe its because the data is already loaded, remove the onload callback like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jandalf/A3DZ6/1/ (look at the console, its working :)

Comment: Many thanks Jan, it works perfectly now, I've posted the updated code. Best regards and thanks again for your patience

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as accepted, so everyone can see that the problem is solved